# JAX-RS converting HashMap with List type as value to XML using Jersey

Tags: java, hashmap, jersey, jax-rs

I have a rest endpoint in which I need to return `Map<String,List<String>`, I have tried wrapping both Map and List to POJOs as well as using GenericEntity to create Response object.

Every time it fails. At the end exception message is like:

> Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer
>   for Java class java.util.HashMap, and Java type
>   `java.util.Map<java.lang.String,  java.util.List<java.lang.String>>`,
>   and MIME media type application/xml was not found.

Can anybody please suggest a solution writing custom writer is not preferred.

Comment: I believe you must create a custom serializer.